# Initialising Queue in Python

Tags: python, queue

I am trying to code my first Queue class. So far I have this code that seemes to work:

```
class Queue(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self = []

    def insert(self, x):
        self.append(x)
        return self

    def delete(self):
        if len(self) == 0:
            print "The queue is empty"
        else:
            self.remove(self[0])
            return self
```

However, I was recomended to rewrite it, and when I try something like this I got wrong results:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def insert(self, x):
        self.items.append(x)
```

Test:

```
queue = Queue()
print queue
queue.insert(5)
print queue
```

Got:

```
<__main__.Queue instance at 0x0000000002A2F148>
<__main__.Queue instance at 0x0000000002A2F148>
```

Could you, please, explain me the difference between two approaches and why the second doesn't work (although I saw it on many websites)?

Comment: Second one works, just override` __str__` or do `print queue.items`

Comment: how would you run your first method and what is the expected output of your second method

Comment: The expected ouputs for the tests (see "Test" above) are [], [5] respectively. I got it using the first code version and following the __str__ advise (Thank you!) with the second code version.

Answer (score 1):

You need need implement either `str` or `repr` for your `class Queue` before printing

Answer (score 0):

Inside the rewrite, you might want to return the value of insert, and in the calling, assign it to a variable:

```
queue = Queue()
print queue #should show something like <__main__.Queue instance at 0x(some numbers here)>
newQueue = queue.insert(5)
print newQueue
```

and inside the function, changing it to something like:

```
def insert(self, x):
    self.items.append(x)
    return self.items
```